# Implement Django REST TokenAuthentication for Multiple User Model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to implement `TokenAuthentication` using Custom user model `Consumer` & `Merchant` (The default `User` model still exists and is used for admin login).

I've been looking on official DRF documentation and days looking on google, but I can't find any detailed reference about how to achieve this, all of the references I found using default User or extended User models.

```
class Consumer(models.Model):
    consumer_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    token = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=uuid.uuid4)


class Merchant(models.Model):
    merchant_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    token = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=uuid.uuid4)
```

Settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
    'rest_framework',
...

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser'
    ]
}
```

I'm also using `@api_view` decorator with function-based views:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@renderer_classes([JSONRenderer])
def inbound_product(request, pid):
    product = MerchantProduct.objects.get(product_id=pid)
```

Comment: You can write your own [authentication class](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/). Though I don't recommend this way of separating your users into groups. You can see an example of custom AuthenticationClass [here](https://gist.github.com/Sajadrahimi/c3f0a92fc6dd306dfd3a185b7e371b28)

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to keep authentication data only on one table even if you have multiple user profile tables.So in you case I think you need to have another table for authenticating the users, the table should implement AbstractBaseUser.
And there should be a OneToOne reference between the merchant and customer tables to the new created user model.
In this case your authentication data will only be kept on one place which is the new table .
please check the following docs link for more info regarding custom authentication models and backends

Comment: this project was just handed over to me, and it's already running on production, and there's no way to change the current 3 user model.